# AVPlayer and MPMoviePlayerController differences

Tags: ios, ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller, avfoundation, avplayer

I am developing an iPhone application that needs to play videos. 
So far, I learned that there are at least two API's for achieving this; `AVPlayer` and `MPMoviePlayerController`.

What are the main differences?

Comment: Tried to reword this question to make sure it is not generating opinion based answers.

Answer (score 173):

**NOTE** as of iOS9, Apple has deprecated the MPMoviePlayerController:

> The MPMoviePlayerController class is formally deprecated in iOS 9. (The MPMoviePlayerViewController class is also formally deprecated.) To play video content in iOS 9 and later, instead use the AVPictureInPictureController or AVPlayerViewController class from the AVKit framework, or the WKWebView class from WebKit.

Copied from the [MPMoviePlayerController reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/).

[**AVPlayer**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer)

`AVPlayer` gives you a lot more flexibility but is pretty poorly documented. Using this API will force you to create your own UI. `AVFoundation` (the framework that brings you `AVPlayer`) generally is a bit hard on the user (coder) as it forces you to use [Key-Value Observing](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) a lot for checking states. The concept of KVO is great, do not get me wrong - still, for unexperienced developers it can be painful to learn. Apple sometimes omits the information on which properties are actually KVO compliant and that will force you to do some experimentation.

One big advantage of `AVPlayer` over `MPMoviePlayerController` would for example be its extended version, `AVQueuePlayer` as that one is able to do gapless playback of multiple movie sources.
Another advantage certainly is the feature rich `AVFoundation` framework allowing you to do things like on-the-fly movie composition / encoding / converting.

Yet another huge advantage of `AVPlayer` is the fact that you may actually play multiple video sources concurrently (e.g. side by side) without any problem.

[**MPMoviePlayerController**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmovieplayercontroller)

`MPMoviePlayerController` is easy to use and covers most needs out of the box. Using this API will give you a good looking and commonly understood UI. The UI however can be disabled and or replaced with a custom one.

For status changes, `MPMoviePlayerController` uses a few `NSNotifications` covering everything the regular App needs.

Under the hood, `MPMoviePlayerController` builds on top of `AVPlayer` - but that actually happens entirely transparent to the user - you have no access to that layer while using `MPMoviePlayerController`.

`MPMoviePlayerController` uses the underlaying `AVPlayer` as a singleton instance, hence it is not possible to use multiple instances of `MPMoviePlayerController` to play videos concurrently.

On the other hand, as soon as you are trying to extend the functionality of `MPMoviePlayerController` with your own features, code quickly gets nasty - e.g. you will possibly start using multiple timers for covering things like a proper starve-detection (actually, that feature got included into iOS5's version of this class), custom UI updates, ... Or you may end up having more than a handful of state properties trying to cover things like gracefully aborting of the playback while the player is still pre-buffering.

---

***Personal Recommendation***

I have used both and I will continue to use both, depending on the needs of the App I have the pleasure to build. 
For most (simple) projects, I would recommend using `MPMoviePlayerController` over `AVPlayer` as it is very simple to use and with just a few lines of code, you get a full-fledged media player. And if your demands on media playback are even simpler, have a peek at [`MPMoviePlayerViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller) (note that View-part).

Comment: AVPlayer also automatically lets you use layer animations. If you want to run Core Animation in the background, don't use an MPMoviePlayerController, though it might have a setting to enable them, just be aware of that if you're using CALayer stuff

Comment: Shouldn't it be:  The UI however **can't** be disabled and or replaced with a custom one?

Comment: No. The answer is correct. The MPMoviePlayerController UI **can** be disabled and or replaced with a custom one.

Comment: @Besi no, entirely correct as written - it definitely can be disabled (using MPMovieControlStyleNone) and hence replaced as there is nothing stopping you from adding your own view as a sibling of MPMoviePlayerController's view or directly on its `backgroundView`.

Comment: I am having a hard time capturing a screen shot of a MPMoviePlayerController, I dont need a thumbnail what I need is a screenshot of the video itself. I wonder if AVPlayer will allow me to do what I need. Thanks.

Comment: As of iOS 9 MPMoviePlayerController is deprecated and so you should use AVPlayer for future projects

Comment: That is super valuable information @lewis42 - will add it to my ancient posting :)